# Postgresql max date in dataset for each month

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following columns (in addition to others):

```
name    char
tanggal date
```

Rows are inserted into this table each day.

How can I get the formatted name for the max date of each month,
for example:

> Jan 31, Feb 28, Mar 31, Apr 30,...

I am using Postgresql 8.3

Comment: What is a tanggal date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `extract` to get the month of the date. From there on, it's a straight forward `group by` query:

```
SELECT   MAX(tanggal)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY EXTRACT (MONTH FROM tanggal)
```